# mb_substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. This project was working perfect on my friends computer on his personal IP but now when I have installed it on mine on localhost, it is continually giving some errors. At first it was displaying the error :

1. > InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php line 14319: View [_particles.sub_header] not found.
2. > SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I think I might not have linked the database to the project correctly due to this it's not working properly.

AND now When I try to open my project through browser it provides me an error

3. > ErrorException in compiled.php line 6772:
   >   mb_substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

**and the code at this line shows:**

```
public static function substr($string, $start, $length = null)
{

    return mb_substr($string, $start, $length, 'UTF-8');

}
```

NOTE: The last error is the current error showing me on my browser.

Comment: How can we help if we dont know where `substr` is called an therefore what is being passed to the functions in the parameters

Comment: All the errors are self explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static function substr($string, $start, $length = null)
{

    if(is_array($string)){
        var_dump($string);
        die();
    }
    return mb_substr($string, $start, $length, 'UTF-8');

}
```

And you will check which array is problem.

Comment: Getting this
`array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "mysql" }`